# Gmail address extraction

Tags: gmail

I would like to extract all e-mail addresses from *my* Gmail account, and extract them from the messages where some search term is satisfied. I don't only want to extract addresses from `to:` and `from:` fields, but from the email’s body as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Free web site** (accepting donations):

[Vallery.net](http://vallery.net/gmail/index.php)
This application will connect to Gmail and extract all of the email addresses.
* look at every single message stored in your Gmail account
* extract all of the email addresses in the from, to, cc, bcc, reply-to, and sender headers
* create a csv file that can be imported into many common sites

**Commercial software:**

[Gmail Extract Email Addresses Software 7.0](http://download.cnet.com/Gmail-Extract-Email-Addresses-Software/3000-2381%5F4-10962226.html?tag=mncol)

> Extract email addresses from your
>   Gmail email account. Save results as
>   text files. You decide which emails to
>   extract email data from. Extract from
>   body or header of email message.
>   Extract from multiple emails.

[GMail Extract e-mail addresses from G-Mail Account 9](http://download.cnet.com/GMail-Extract-e-mail-addresses-from-G-Mail-Account/3000-2649%5F4-10896302.html?tag=mncol)

> If you have a G-Mail account, and want
>   to create a newsletter to which you
>   can send a bunch of e-mails at once,
>   instead of having to sort through
>   individual e-mail addresses, then this
>   software is for you! With this
>   software, you can easily: Extract
>   e-mail addresses from your g-mail
>   account(s). You can select which
>   standard mailboxes you want to
>   search/extract e-mails from You can
>   then save the resulting list to a
>   textfile, having quickly download.

EDIT:

[Email Extractor - web email addresses harvester](http://www.massmailsoftware.com/extractweb/)
This is shareware. See this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oq6Im3ooQoo) for an example.

> Atomic Email Hunter is an email
>   extractor designed to harvest e-mail
>   addresses and user names from the web
>   sites you define (or those found
>   basing on keywords) and using http and
>   https protocols.

Note: I haven't tried any of them (not using gmail, sorry).

Comment: vallery & gmail extract 9: no search
gmail extract 7: crashes :(

Comment: I found a 3rd one, edited into my answer. If this doesn't work, then follow the advice given by mklappstuhl.

Comment: Theres one at www.starbanana.com which I use every now and then, its simple but does the job.

Answer (score 3):

i dont know an easier way:

1. download all your emails
2. write a small program that searches in every email for email adresses (regex)

Comment: For one, I have tons of mail stored on gmail.  Second, if I filter it, and if I could retrieve filtered list, that would still be inapropriate (some several thousand e-mails).

Comment: first: any software which has to look at every single word of your mails has to download every single word of your tons of emails to analyze it.

second: why does it matter how long the 'grep' runs? if you want the result, then wait once and then you have the list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, though the IMAP or POP3 functionality of GMail, you can access all your emails to analyse them on your local system. Outlook would be able to use both techniques. But to extract email addresses from any message in your mailbox, you would need some more specialized software. Problem is, such software is popular by bulk emailers to collect existing email addresses. Thus, anyone who would create such an application could end up belong accused of creating software to support spammers and bulk emailers.

So, first of all, what are your intentions? What are you planning to do with this information?

Then, while it would require special tools to collect this information, it's not too difficult to write such software yourself. I wrote something similar myself, in an anti-spam attempt to collect information about spammers. It's not that difficult and with simple regular expressions it's even quite simple.

Of course, there are probably several such tools available on the Internet. But be aware about the reasons someone would create such a tool! A website, for example, that would offer such functionality could also be harvesting email addresses for spammers. Other tools might also misuse an internet connection to send harvested email addresses to the creator of this tool, allowing spammers to build enormous lists of confirmed email addresses.

One thing is sure, though. If I knew I was sending emails to someone who would collect them for any purpose, I would blacklist that person for my regular accounts and only communicate with them with a throw-away account just to make sure I won't be bothered too much by spam.

Comment: your last paragraph makes absolutely no sense at all, especially not since you "wrote something similar myself, in an anti-spam attempt to collect information about spammers" ... does this mean your mum has to contact you via throw-away-mails? by the same argument you are not allowed to write any mails to people who use virus-scanners or anti-spam software :) and software, which extracts email-address does not belong into the "support spammer" category per se ...

Comment: The throw-away account will exist as long as it doesn't receive a lot of spam. Once spam starts to flood it, I'll discard it. In general, I use such accounts when registering products or signing up for mailing lists. Often just one account per company/list thus I can detect who is leaking my account data. My mom and other trusted persons know my direct accounts, although a throw-away account is sometimes handy when family members start using all kinds of online services to send you invites and comical articles, not realizing that thoose actions might result in more spam for me...

Comment: Although I must say that GMail tends to be real good at filtering spam from the regular emails. I get about three spam messages per day, per account.

Comment: the point of using throw-away-accounts is obvious. i was just pointing at the logical flaws of your argumentation. our little chit chat does not solve the answer anyway.

Comment: Well, I received 3 free mail accounts from my ISP. I don't use those. I have about 10 different GMail accounts, one for family, one for friends and colleagues and the rest for the more reliable companies. Then I have a few domains where I can generate unlimited accounts and just use a catch-all to get all. Those are used for less reliable mailing lists and sites that ask registration. When one of the accounts starts to receive too much spam, I can check who started it and block the account, thus bouncing all messages.

Comment: This is not an answer but a rant on spammers.  I asked how I could extract e-mail addresses from MY gmail account, not from other sources.  If it is in my mailbox, I guess that I own it in some fashion, and that people that talked to me know me and know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to hayymc's list. http://www.gmailextractor.com Unlike other services you dont need to give your password to any third party and you will be logging-in to Gmail account through Google. gmailextractor.com will only extract Email addresses in "From" field and also the Sender's Name if available in the mail header.

Comment: how safe is gmailextractor.com in terms of privacy etc.

Comment: I dont trust it, comments say it cheats and saves your addresses!!! not good.